Understanding capacitive reading out circuit for mems accelerometer
I am trying to understand how the circuit on the left of the following picture produces the output on the right. The picture is a (simplified) model of a readout circuit for a mems accelerometer from this paper page 6.

For me the part with the Op amp looks like an integrator circuit that should give us an antiderivative of the input signal (VREF). But the signal on the right doesn't look like an antiderivative of the input.
I also don't see why this should be depend on the value of the Sensor capacitance. Because the output should be
$$
\frac{1}{R_{FB} C_{FB}} \int V_{REF} (t) dt
$$
Where \$R_{RB}\$ is the Resistance before \$C_{FB}\$ or maybe in this case the resistance of the wire.
Then I tried to simulate the circuit here, but I wasn't able to reproduce the signal on the paper and the signal didn't seem to depend on the value of \$C = C_{S0} + \Delta C_S\$. Note that I didn't know the correct order of magnitudes for the components in the case of a mems accelerometer readout, so I tried just to reproduce the principal behaviour.
So what did I do wrong?

You circuit in Falstad is not the same than original. It is the capacitor "change" that should make "sense".

@Antonio51 I just added two resistors to make the simulation work. The capacitor \Delta C is just modelled by changing the capacitance of C_S0 by the slider. Are there additional differences?

You applied the pulsed voltage in the wrong place. In the given circuit, it is connected to Vref, but in your simulation, it's connected across the sense capacitor.

I don't "do" Falstad, but here is the circuit in CircuitLab used on this site.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The 1 GΩ resistor just keeps the simulator from complaining about the floating node.
When C1 varies from 10 pF to 20 pF, you get the following family of output waveforms.


Thanks. I am not quite sure, of how to change it. May you post a link to a modified version of the simulation?

The opamp feedback component from output to -ve input terminal allows the opamp to drive the -ve input terminal to match the voltage on the +ve input terminal.
As Vref is driven by a squarewave, the -ve input will reproduce that squarewave.
In order to apply that squarewave to Cs, the parallel combination of Cso and dCs, a current has to flow into them.
That current cannot flow through the -ve input, so it flows through Cfb, generating a voltage across it. This voltage appears on the output, as a function of dCs.
For an alternative way of visualizing what is happening, consider that Cfb and Cs form a voltage divider network back to the -ve input of the opamp, giving it a gain of (Cfb+Cs)/Cs. As Cs varies, the gain varies, and so does the output voltage, as a function of Cs.
In a simulator, if the opamp model does not have a DC path to ground from the -ve input, that node will be floating, and so the initial DC solve step will fail. The addition of a resistance to ground will make the simulator happy. The resistor can be as large as will work for the numeric precision of the simulator.

Thanks. Regarding the simulation: If I connect -ve to ground, it is the same as connecting -ve to +ve (since +ve is connecte to ground), so it might looking like this: https://tinyurl.com/29jkb2y6 did I understand you correctly? However I don't see why this makes sense and it doesn't seem to bring the desired Cs dependency into the simulation. So I guess that I didn't understand you correctly. Maybe you could just post a link to a modified simulation.

@Julia connecting -ve input to ground stops it working. Connect a 100 megohm resistor from -ve input to ground to make the simulator's DC solve step happy. It does nothing to change the actual operation of the capacitive sensor. Engineers tend not to use Falstad.
